# Como ler yaml com php

Tags: php, html, symfony, yaml

Olá, estou abrindo um servidor de Minecraft (jogo java) e me deparei com a seguinte necessidade:

Para cada servidor de minecraft é necessário a construção de um site informativo. Ao construir o site, criei uma pagina simples apenas com a lista da equipa do servidor. A equipa é constituída por "Ajudantes", "Moderadores" e "Administradores". Para atribuir um destes cargos a um jogador, é necessário introduzir um comando dentro do jogo, que logo este será validado no ficheiro config.yml do servidor.

Este é o ficheiro config.yml que define o estatuto dos jogadores:

```
users:
      JamesMarch:
        group:
        - Admin
      TheCountess_:
        group:
        - Admin
      mumiant_:
        group:
        - Moderador
      Pequena20:
        group:
        - Ajudante
      nana34piu:
        group:
        - Ajudante
```

O que eu estava pensando era criar um "leitor" em php, que lesse o código yaml e os cargos dos jogadores no meu site do seguinte jeito:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Alderaan Minecraft Server</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Staff</h1>
            <h2>Administradores</h2>
                <p>JamesMarch</p>
                <p>TheCountess_</p>
            <h2>Moderador</h2>
                <p>mumiant_</p>
            <h2>Ajudantes</h2>
                <p>Pequena20</p>
                <p>nana34piu</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Gostaria ainda que em cada paragrafo da staff aparecesse o nome de cada membro, por ordem alfabética, exemplo:

> Administradores
>
> - JamesMarch
> - TheCountess_

e não

> Administradores
>
> - TheCountess_
> - JamesMarch

Gostaria também que, por exemplo, se houver apenas um Administrador, apareça "Administrador" e não “Administradores”, exemplo:

Casa haja um administrador:

> **Administrador**
>
> - JamesMarch

Casa hajam dois ou mais administradores:

> Administrador**es**
>
> - JamesMarch
> - TheCountess_

Tambem queria que fosse possivel **aparecer apenas os tres cargos no web site**, uma vez que o site possui mais que tres cargos, eu gostava que apenas os cargos de **"Administrador", "Moderador" e "Ajudante"** aparecessem na pagina.

Por ultimo, queria que aparecessem os cargos pela hierarquia, exemplo:

**Certo:**

> Administradores
>
> - JamesMarch
> - TheCountess_
>
> Moderador
>
> - mumiant_
>
> Ajudantes
>
> - nana34piu
> - Pequena20

**Errado:**

> Ajudantes
>
> - nana34piu
> - Pequena20
>
> Administradores
>
> - JamesMarch
> - TheCountess_
>
> Moderador
>
> - mumiant_

Answer (score 2):

### Instalando leitores de Yml

Se o teu servidor permitir instalar algo você pode instalar/compilar o http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML, baixe http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.7.tar.gz e depois compile:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
# make install
```

E depois instale via *PECL*, pode baixar aqui http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml

### Symfony

Você pode instalar o pacote do Symfony usando `composer`, execute no seu projeto isto:

```
composer require symfony/yaml
```

Ou adicione no seu arquivo `composer.json` o `symfony/yaml` e depois execute:

```
composer update
```

Para usar faça isto:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;

try {
    $value = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('arquivo.yml'));
} catch (ParseException $e) {
    printf("Impossivel decodificar o YAML: %s", $e->getMessage());
}
```

### Lendo o yml da pergunta

O teu .yml parece estar em um formato inválido, suponho que o correto seria isto:

```
users:
    JamesMarch:
        group:
        - Admin
    TheCountess_:
        group:
        - Admin
    mumiant_:
        group:
        - Moderador
    Pequena20:
        group:
        - Ajudante
    nana34piu:
        group:
        - Ajudante
```

O resultado deve ser mais ou menos isto:

> Note que tive que reorganizar o array em um estrutura para poder montar o HTML mais facilmente, fazendo o uso da variável `$porcargo`

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException;

$conteudo = file_get_contents('config.yml');

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$porcargo = array();

try {
    $ymlParsed = Yaml::parse($conteudo);
    foreach ($ymlParsed['users'] as $nome => $cargos) {
        $grupo = $cargos['group'];
        $j = count($grupo);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
            if (!isset($porcargo[ $grupo[$i] ])) {
                $porcargo[ $grupo[$i] ] = array();
            }

            $porcargo[ $grupo[$i] ][] = $nome;
        }
    }
} catch (ParseException $e) {
    die(sprintf("Unable to parse the YAML string: %s", $e->getMessage()));
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Alderaan Minecraft Server</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Staff</h1>
            <?php foreach ($porcargo as $cargo => $usuarios): ?>

            <h2><?php echo $cargo; ?></h2>

                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($usuarios); $i++): ?>

                    <p><?php echo $usuarios[$i]; ?></p>

                <?php endfor; ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [yaml-parse-file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.yaml-parse-file.php) é a forma estruturada de Yaml::parse correto?

Comment: @Everson Creio eu que `Yaml::parse` é um pacote de symfony independente do `LibYAML` e do http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml, de uma olhada no source-code: https://github.com/symfony/yaml/blob/master/Parser.php#L88